# Java netbeans persistence Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am trying to connect a Myqsl database from Netbeans using Java. I use persistence. I manage to create the persistence: I connect to the database and get the entities and the JPA controllers from the base, but in my program I want to record, edit or delete data from the database, and that's where the program doesn't work. It goes straight to the catch and doesn't execute the try.

I use Netbeans 12.1, Mysql 8.0, the Mysql connector mysql-connector-java-8.0.22, JDK 13, and the EclipseLink library (JPA 2.1) but I can't write to the database. I think the problem is the connector. I have used many versions prior to 8.0.22 but the same thing happens to me in all of them. I manage to obtain that data, but I cannot modify the database. This is persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="OtraBasePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ladb?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="dferazo"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="dferazo1234"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is the file that tries to make changes, the question is that it goes directly to the cathc:

```java
public class gestionAsignatura {

  private AsignaturaJpaController gestAsignatura = new AsignaturaJpaController();
  private Asignatura asignatura = new Asignatura();
  private String mensaje = "";

  public String insertarAsignatura(int id, String nombre, String codigo) {
    try {
      asignatura.setIdAsignatura(id);
      asignatura.setCodigoAsignatura(codigo);
      asignatura.setNombreAsignatura(nombre);

      gestAsignatura.create(asignatura);
      mensaje = "Se guardó.";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Mensaje insertar: " + e.getMessage());
      mensaje = "No se guardó.";
    }

    return mensaje;
  }

  public String actualizarAsignatura(int id, String nombre, String codigo) {
    try {
      asignatura.setIdAsignatura(id);
      asignatura.setNombreAsignatura(nombre);
      asignatura.setCodigoAsignatura(codigo);

      gestAsignatura.edit(asignatura);
      mensaje = "Se actualizó.";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Mensaje insertar: " + e.getMessage());
      mensaje = "No se actualizó.";
    }
    return mensaje;
  }

  public String eliminarAsignatura(int id) {
    try {
      gestAsignatura.destroy(id);
      mensaje = "Se eliminó";
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Mensaje eliminar: " + e.getMessage());
      mensaje = "No se eliminó";
    }
    return mensaje;
  }
}
```

It does not give me errors but this appears in the console:

```
run:
[EL Info]: 2020-12-20 19:24:16.005--ServerSession(341853399)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2020-12-20 19:24:16.43--ServerSession(341853399)--file:/C:/Users/cuera/Documents/NetBeansProjects/OtraBase/build/classes/_OtraBasePU login successful
[EL Warning]: metamodel: 2020-12-20 19:24:16.453--The collection of metamodel types is empty. Model classes may not have been found during entity search for Java SE and some Java EE container managed persistence units. Please verify that your entity classes are referenced in persistence.xml using either <class> elements or a global <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> element
Mensaje insertar: Unknown entity bean class: class entidad.Asignatura, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
No se guardó.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

This is the file structure:

[image: file structure]

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the fault is in the connector.  Rather, I think the problem is EITHER that you haven't marked your entity classes with an `@Entity` annotation, OR your `persistence.xml` file is incorrect ... as per the messages on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Tks so much. This is one entity class, I have this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asignatura")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Asignatura.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Asignatura a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Asignatura.findByIdAsignatura", query = "SELECT a FROM Asignatura a WHERE a.idAsignatura = :idAsignatura"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Asignatura.findBySemestreAsignatura", query = "SELECT a FROM Asignatura a WHERE a.semestreAsignatura = :semestreAsignatura"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Asignatura.findByHorasAsignatura", query = "SELECT a FROM Asignatura a WHERE a.horasAsignatura = :horasAsignatura"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Asignatura.findByCreditosAsignatura", query = "SELECT a FROM Asignatura a WHERE a.creditosAsignatura = :creditosAsignatura")})
public class Asignatura implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_asignatura")
    private Integer idAsignatura;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "codigo_asignatura")
    private String codigoAsignatura;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "nombre_asignatura")
    private String nombreAsignatura;
    @Column(name = "semestre_asignatura")
    private Integer semestreAsignatura;
    @Column(name = "horas_asignatura")
    private Integer horasAsignatura;
    @Column(name = "creditos_asignatura")
    private Integer creditosAsignatura;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "dependencia_asignatura")
    private String dependenciaAsignatura;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_carrera", referencedColumnName = "id_carrera")
    @ManyToOne
    private Carrera idCarrera;

    public Asignatura() {
    }

    public Asignatura(Integer idAsignatura) {
        this.idAsignatura = idAsignatura;
    }

    public Integer getIdAsignatura() {
        return idAsignatura;
    }

    public void setIdAsignatura(Integer idAsignatura) {
        this.idAsignatura = idAsignatura;
    }

    public String getCodigoAsignatura() {
        return codigoAsignatura;
    }

    public void setCodigoAsignatura(String codigoAsignatura) {
        this.codigoAsignatura = codigoAsignatura;
    }

    public String getNombreAsignatura() {
        return nombreAsignatura;
    }

    public void setNombreAsignatura(String nombreAsignatura) {
        this.nombreAsignatura = nombreAsignatura;
    }

    public Integer getSemestreAsignatura() {
        return semestreAsignatura;
    }

    public void setSemestreAsignatura(Integer semestreAsignatura) {
        this.semestreAsignatura = semestreAsignatura;
    }

    public Integer getHorasAsignatura() {
        return horasAsignatura;
    }

    public void setHorasAsignatura(Integer horasAsignatura) {
        this.horasAsignatura = horasAsignatura;
    }

    public Integer getCreditosAsignatura() {
        return creditosAsignatura;
    }

    public void setCreditosAsignatura(Integer creditosAsignatura) {
        this.creditosAsignatura = creditosAsignatura;
    }

    public String getDependenciaAsignatura() {
        return dependenciaAsignatura;
    }

    public void setDependenciaAsignatura(String dependenciaAsignatura) {
        this.dependenciaAsignatura = dependenciaAsignatura;
    }

    public Carrera getIdCarrera() {
        return idCarrera;
    }

    public void setIdCarrera(Carrera idCarrera) {
        this.idCarrera = idCarrera;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idAsignatura != null ? idAsignatura.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Asignatura)) {
            return false;
        }
        Asignatura other = (Asignatura) object;
        if ((this.idAsignatura == null && other.idAsignatura != null) || (this.idAsignatura != null && !this.idAsignatura.equals(other.idAsignatura))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entidad.Asignatura[ idAsignatura=" + idAsignatura + " ]";
    }
    
}
```

I dont understand where is the error.... personally i think the persistence.xml is ok, because yes i can get the data from the DB to create the JPA entities and controllers .... but maybe there is something wrong ...